# Jackson JSON mapper by Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

My question is very simple, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder works only in the serialization of a response and not in the serialization of a request?

Thanks!

Comment: No.............

Comment: @luk2302 Ok, but why when I define a DTO object (with annotation '@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)' as parameter on my controller (@RequestBody ) that object contains null fileds?

Comment: You use POST request, right? It seems like you don't send data with request.

Comment: Yes, I purposely sent null fields. What I would expect is that when the content of the application arrives through '@RequestBody' param that object only contains only full fields y not null fields. 
In other words, I hope that the structure of the object that comes through '@RequestBody'  is transformed

Comment: I have to say I really do not like the way you phrase the question. Why don't you give us the full picture but instead ask something like a trick question upfront? You do realize that "no" is the only acceptable answer to this question and this post is done. You are not supposed to add further question in the comments.

Comment: What are you talking about, with two different questions and the answer you gave is not explanatory, it seems unfair that you rate this question badly.

Comment: You ask "does it *only* work with ...?", therefore "no" is perfectly acceptable. And the fact that you are not getting any more answers / information confirms that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: no, Jackson can deserialize JSON to objects, and serialize objects back to JSON. It's a very powerful library.

You should first clarify the behavior you see, and the expected one, so it's easier to know what's going on.

The simplest code I can give you is:

```
class DemoApplication {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run DemoApplication, args
    }
    @PostMapping("/")
    String greet(@RequestBody Greeting greeting) {
        return "Hello ${greeting.name}, with email ${greeting.email}"
    }
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
class Greeting {
  String name
  String email
}
```

And some simple CURL requests to that endpoint:

```
~ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8080
{"timestamp":"2018-04-22T21:18:39.849+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.example.demo.DemoApplication.greet(com.example.demo.Greeting)","path":"/"}

~ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8080  -d '{}'
Hello null, with email null                                                                     

~ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8080  -d '{"name": "AlejoDev"}'
Hello AlejoDev, with email null                                                                    

~ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8080  -d '{"name": "AlejoDev", "email":"info@alejodev.com"}'
Hello AlejoDev, with email info@alejodev.com
```

So, when sending no data, Spring will send back an exception back to the client, with an error code 400 (Bad Request).

Anything else (sending an empty object, or data on it) will just work fine, setting fields to null when required.

Can you post your code?